# How do I call a custom method for an object?

Tags: ruby

I have a class with several methods:

```
class Test
  def initialize (age, height)
    @age = age
    @height = height
  end

  def older
    @age = @age + 2
  end

  def shorter
    @height = @height - 5
  end
end

man = Test.new(40, 170)
man.older
man.shorter

[...]
```

I want to pass onto object `man` a custom method, that is, I want to write something like `man.variablemethod` and set `.variablemethod` to either `.older` or `.shorter`, depending on some other factors. How can I do that?

I figured out that I can call "`if condition then man.older`", but I do not want to use `if`, especially when I have twenty different methods to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need [`send`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Object#send-instance_method):

```
man.send(method_name)
```

You can pass a string or symbol representing the name of the method you wish to call, even pass additional arguments too:

```
def man.older_by_increment(years)
  @age += years
end

man.send(:older_by_increment, 7)
```

This also allows you to call private and protected methods from anywhere:

```
class Man

  # ...

  private

  def weight
    @weight
  end
end

Man.new.weight         # => private method `weight' called for #<Man:0x10bc956d8> (NoMethodError)
Man.new.send(:weight)  # => @weight
```

Comment: omg, that's what I need! :)) how did I miss out on that? Thanks!